# Do we extract snapshot of data or updated data if data is being updated in the database table?

Tags: sql, ssis, sql-update, extract, upsert

Good Day Team,

We have to extract data from the SQL database tables which are updated (upsert) on an hourly basis and takes approx 15 minutes to update. We have to extract all tables within 1 hour to get the same data as our target table (which uses these source tables). 1 table is too huge and is taking almost 5 hours to extract.

Now my question is suppose I have a table XYZ which takes 5 hours to extract and I have started extracting data at 12 PM, do I get static data of 12 PM even if XYZ has been updated again at 1 PM, 2 PM, 3 PM, 4 PM, 5 PM or we get updated data of 5 PM.

Note: I am using SSIS

Apologies if this is a very basic question, I am not that familiar with SQL know-how.

Comment: It depends on your query's isolation level

Comment: I might be mistaken but I believe the default isolation level for data source components are uncommitted

Comment: You would be mistaken - the default isolation level for a package is Serializable the polar opposite of uncommitted/chaos ;)

Comment: @billinkc, I'll keep that in mind next time, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data source scans over the table, you would get the record version at time of read.

The time of read could be anytime in that 5 hour window. You could reduce the impact by adding an order clause to your source component so that the latest data gets read and transferred last. This would ensure the data you expect to get the most updates during those 5 hours to catch the most upserts

If the upsert updates a record that has already been copied over in that 5 hour window then you will miss the update

Ultimately you would need to look at a incremental load design if you need to catch every single upsert